# Why mysqli_num_rows always returns NULL?

Tags: php, mysql, apache, http

I want to count the rows in the users table with specific name and pwd which should be 1 if existed.
  but the result always return null(not 0),no matter whether the user existed or not.
  I even change the query simple to "SELECT * FROM users", and it ended with the same result.
  And I am pretty sure that the name of the DATABASE and TABLE are true,and the table is not empty!

By the way,why I have to use "@" symbol before "mysqli_query" in order to get rid of error?
  thx!

```
enter code here
<?php
   #$mysql_db_hostname = "localhost";
   $mysql_db_hostname = "127.0.0.1";
   $mysql_db_user = "root";
   $mysql_db_password = "";
   $mysql_db_database = "smartFSUsers";
   $con = mysqli_connect($mysql_db_hostname, $mysql_db_user,       $mysql_db_password,$mysql_db_database);
   if (!$con) {
       trigger_error('Could not connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
     }
   $name = $_GET["name"];
   $password = $_GET["password"];
   $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE name='$name' AND password='$password'";
   $result =@mysqli_query($query,$con);
   echo($result);
   $row=@mysqli_num_rows($result);
   echo"the row num is $row \n";
   ?>
```

Comment: Using `@` in front of a function call hides the error. It's a much better idea to leave the `@` off, and fix the error.

Comment: Perhaps if you weren't plugging your ears and going "lalalalalala can't hear you" by using the `@` error suppression operator, you could actually get some error messages/warnings from your code. Plus, lovely [SQL injection attack](http://bobby-tables.com) vulnerabilities. Enjoy having your server pwn3d.

Comment: And while we're on the topic of doing things properly, you're open to SQL injection!

Comment: Why should I check for vulnerabilities or errors. I'm just going to do the Dr.Evil style pinky finger to the corner of my mouth, and **"No no no, I'm going to make a function call, and not check if an error occurred, I'm just gonna assume it all went to plan. What?"**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RTM: http://php.net/mysqli_query

```
$result =@mysqli_query($query,$con);
```

You've got your parameters reversed. `$con` MUST come first:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die(mysqli_error());
```

If you had bothered adding error correction to your code, you'd have been told about this. But nope, you opted for `@` to hide all those error messages.

Comment: It'd be better to just include the correct code instead of the broken example as well.

Comment: @tadman: far too many people go and ret-con their question to hide the errors.

Comment: Perhaps. I think your fixed version stands on its own and the other one just gets in the way.